# Lightning design system for lightning component : question about icons

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, slds

I'm creating a lightning component using the Lightning design system. I learned that I could add the SLDS design to a lightning app with that : `extends="force:slds"`. This way all the element in my page are styling with SLDS and I havn't to add the `ltng:require` tag with the SLDS stylesheet.

But I'd like to add the SLDS icons in my component, I follow [this tutorial](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/) to add an icon with a static ressource. But my question is, am I obliged to use a static ressouce containing the icons, or is there a way to get these icons with the `extends="force:slds"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible if you use the `lightning:icon` [standard component.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm)

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
</aura:component>
```

See the [Lightning Design System](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/icons) for a list of all icons and their categories.

Comment: Thank you, it's working, I havn't see this documentation, it's very helpful.

Comment: One note: the lighting:icon will probably work for most cases, but there are some LDS examples, like [section title](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/text/#flavor-section-title-section-title-open), where you need control over the CSS class applied on the <svg> tag itself. lightning:icon only allows you to put CSS on the *outer* wrapping HTML element, not on the <svg> tag itself.